# refresh a listview in a collapsible set jquery mobile. Mines not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I am having a problem with my list view being view able. I am calling a web service from $.post method from j query and returning a data set. All of my data and information displays on the page but the listview I have inside my collapsible set is not refreshing after I call listview.refresh. Here is my code:

```
$("#button").on("vclick",function()
{
   data = {}
   $.post("Web service",data,function(data1)
   {
      //clear the page
       $("#list containing the data-role collapsible set").html("");
       type = data.type;
       $.each(data1.ArrayName,function(i,value)
       {
           if(value.type != current)
           {
              $("div data-role='collapsible' data-collapse='false'><h3> +
              current + </h3><p class='add'></p></div>").appendTo("list containing +
               The data-role collapsible set");
               $('.add').append("<ul data-role='listview' class='list2'></ul>");
               current = type;
           }
           $(".list2").append("<li><a><div><span style='float:left'>" + data.info +
           "</span></div></a></li>");
           $("id for div with data-role collapsibleset").collapsibleset("refresh");
           $(".list2").listview("refresh");
       },"json");

   }
});
```

Comment: try this `$(".listdoc2").listview();`, without `refresh`, it could be that the listview is not initialized

Comment: wat is `listdoc2` here ?  I can see `list2` is your class for `ul`. you should do   `$(".list2").listview("refresh");`